# Why is Vim telling me that 'no plugin to install' when I have installed a plugin manager (vim-plug)?

Tags: vimrc, original-vim, plugin

```
call plug#begin()
plug 'https://github.com/AndrewLockVI/dark_ocean.vim'
plug 'https://github.com/ErichDonGubler/vim-sublime-monokai'
plug 'https://github.com/rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes'
call plug#end()
```

no plugin to install

Comment: I suppose the body of your question is an excerpt of your `.vimrc` file. Did you restart Vim? Did you run `:PlugInstall`? Why do you think the plugin are not installed?

Comment: What is the result of the command: `:colorscheme dark_ocean`?

Comment: I have fixed it. The problem was that :Plug was writen as :plug (case-sensetive).

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt After I managed to install and put the command :colorscheme sublimemonokai it is giving me an error, 'cannot find colorscheme sublimemonokai.'

Comment: So what should I do to fix this problem of colorscheme not found error?

Comment: Did you ran `:PlugInstall`?  Do you have a folder `.vim/plugged/vim-sublime-monokai`?

Comment: Did you followed the instructions in my answer to install the distribution `dark_ocean` or did you gave up on that one?

Comment: "I have fixed it." Please post an answer (however short). You will be able to accept your own answer after two days. Thanks.

Comment: Yes @VivianDeSmedt I ran :PlugInstall and everything was installed. After doing this, then I tried all the colorschemes but I am getting the same error (cannot find colorscheme<name>). This error is showing when opening vim.

Comment: @Friedrich are you taliking about how I fixed the issue?

Comment: BTW, vim-plug will prepend `https://github.com/` so it's sufficient to have `Plug 'USER/REPO'`. And why install three color schemes? You can only use one at a time.

Comment: @Artisan yes, you said you fixed the typo. I understand another problem cropped up but that's another thing. Please [edit] your question or ask another one. Here's the rationale [Can I answer my own question?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Where is the command `colorscheme sublimemonokai` relative to the `Plug 'ndrewLockVI/dark_ocean.vim'` before or after. I suspect it should be after.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt it is before. Let me change and put it after.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt 'colorscheme sublimemonokai' has worked after putting it after 'call plug#end()' but 'dark_ocean' didn't work.

Comment: @Friedrich the reason why I installed three colorschemes, is because I want to try them all since this is my first time doing this with Vim (Vim beginner).

Answer (score 2):

[![Updated][1]][1]

The command to register a plugin in vim-plug is :Plug, not :plug; command names are case-sensitive in Vim. For the correct way, check the screenshot of my .vimrc here
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/07MY5.png